# React-spring with gatsby - error while installing

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-spring

I'm trying to add react-spring to gatsby (Gatsby 3.13.0, React 17.0.2). When I type "npm i react-spring" such an error appears:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0  || ^17.0.0" from @react-spring/core@9.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-spring/core
npm ERR!     @react-spring/core@"~9.2.0" from react-spring@9.2.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-spring
npm ERR!       react-spring@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-reconciler@0.20.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-zdog/node_modules/react-reconciler
npm ERR!   react-reconciler@"^0.20.4" from react-zdog@1.0.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-zdog
npm ERR!     peer react-zdog@">=1.0" from @react-spring/zdog@9.2.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-spring/zdog
npm ERR!       @react-spring/zdog@"~9.2.0" from react-spring@9.2.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-spring
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

I tried --force, or --legacy-peer-deps, but it doesn't help. Is it a problem with React 17 or Gatsby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install the specific target you are using. For example, since you're using `gatsby` I assume you'll want `@react-spring/web` this should resolve the issue with `npm@7`.